# What is the popular challenge of solving the Rubik cube as quickly as possible using LEGO bricks?

Tags: mindstorms, robotic

I saw videos of people participating in a race to resolve a Rubik cube as quickly as possible using Mindstorm LEGO robots.

Can you provide information whether there is a competition and on who is involved?
What is the research/design process? 
Is there any sponsorship? 
What are the performance obtained?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no "race" as this has been solved multiple times by different people ([solving rubik's cube isn't that hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik%27s_Cube)). just take a look at [the CubeStormer](http://www.botjunkie.com/2010/02/15/cubestormer-lego-mindstorms-rubiks-cube-robot/) (or, better, the [CubeStormer II](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5t2hXuSlETc)).

I also saw building-plans and programs for such a cube-solver (not exactly the linked one). If you like to rebuild such a thing: I'll add links as soon as i find them.

**EDIT:**
As promised, there's the [Tilted Twister](http://tiltedtwister.com/tt2download.html) with building plans online. See it in action on [this youtube-video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fAn5A0HbhU). This is very slow compared to the CubeStormer, but looks like it can be built using only the NXT2.0-pack and doesn't need thousands of parts and multiple expensive NXT-logic-blocks.

Comment: I beg to differ :) The race to lower the cube solving time is still on.  http://gizmodo.com/5850505/rubiks-solving-cubesolver-ii-finally-bests-humanity

The plans for the tilted twister in your answer are awesome!

Comment: The Tilted Twister is great!